# Google apps API, is it possible to search the text of a presentation?

Tags: full-text-search, google-docs-api, presentation

I'd like to produce a list of all of the words that appear in a google docs presentation.  I thought that the API would allow this, but it only seems that the spreadsheets API allows searching of the contents of the document?

Answer (score 0):

This is correct, you can't get the content of the presentation with the Documents List API, but you can easily [download an exported version](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#downloading_presentations) of a presentation, for example:

```
GET https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/presentations/Export
           ?docID=0AsJD12345&exportFormat=txt
```

You can use plain text output and just split up the words.